# My code reports an error code 1054 (unknown column)

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I fix my code so it runs correctly? It keeps telling me I have Error Code:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Number_Of_Ticketed_Events' in 'order clause').

Below is my code

```
SELECT Venue.VenueID, Venue.Capacity, VenueName, 
        COUNT(*) AS Number_Of_Ticketed_Events 
FROM (
     (Events INNER JOIN Non_Ticketed_Events)
    INNER JOIN Venue ON Venue.VenueID = Events.VenueID
    )
GROUP BY Events.VenueID
ORDER BY Number_Of_Ticketed_Events DESC;
```

Comment: Which columns are being used to join `Events` to `Non_Ticketed_Events`

Comment: get rid of the parenthesis on the from section, add `ON events.somecolumn = non_ticke....someColumn` after the first inner join

Comment: ALL those brackets are just getting in the way

Comment: Weird, this worked for me as-is on sqlfiddle without any errors.

Comment: Then show us the fiddle @RBarryYoung

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sure: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7fb4e/1

Answer (score 0):

Each JOIN needs telling which columns to use to make the join between the 2 tables

```
SELECT Venue.VenueID, Venue.Capacity, VenueName, 
        COUNT(*) AS Number_Of_Ticketed_Events 
FROM Events e
    INNER JOIN Non_Ticketed_Events nt ON Events.someColumn = nt.someColumn
    INNER JOIN Venue ON Venue.VenueID = Events.VenueID

 . . .
```